# While predicting the test result the reshape function is causing an error.(AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'reshape')

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, data-science, spyder, reshape

## [image: on line 45 reshape function causing an error] Import the libraries

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
```

## Importing the data set

```py
dataset = pd.read_csv("50_Startups.csv")

x = dataset.iloc[:, :-1]
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1]

print(x)
print(y)
```

## Handling categorical data

```py
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

ct  = ColumnTransformer(transformers = [('encoder', OneHotEncoder() , [3])], remainder = 'passthrough')

x = np.array(ct.fit_transform(x))

print(x)
```

## Splitting the dataset into training set and test set

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

print(x_train)

print(x_test)

print(y_train)

print(y_test)
```

## Training the multiple linear regression on the training set

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

regressor = LinearRegression()

regressor.fit(x_train ,y_train)
```

## Predicting thye test results

```py
y_pred = regressor.predict(x_test)

np.set_printoptions(precision=2)

print(np.concatenate((y_pred.reshape(len(y_pred),1), y_test.reshape(len(y_test),1)),1))
```

Comment: Figure out why the relevant variable is a Series instead of an array.

Answer (score 0):

While assigning the independent variables and dependant variable to `x` and `y`, you forget to use `.values`.

So, the type of variables `x` and `y` is `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>` instead of numpy array which caused the error

## Importing the data set

```py
dataset = pd.read_csv("50_Startups.csv")

x = dataset.iloc[: , :-1].values

y = dataset.iloc[: , -1].values
```